# Cant attach Physics material to the player.Unity2D

Tags: unity-game-engine, physics

I cant drag my physics material into the player,i know this might be a stupid question but i have been trying for waaaay to long.(sorry for bad english)

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have created a "physics material 2D", not the normal "physics material" (which is for 3D colliders only). It's hidden somewhere in a tab.
I was confused the first time too...

Comment: Thanks a bunch it helped alot.Im really thankful.                                                                                   Have a great day goodsir.